# Replacing revoked SSL with a new cert but domain still showing old revoked cert

Tags: tls

I bought and installed a SSL cert for my domain but then changed my mind and canceled the purchase and bought a slightly cheaper one. The old cert is then revoked and I proceed to install the new cert.

Here is when things got worse. The domain still showing old revoked SSL and that makes my site couldn't be loaded on Firefox or any browser which are using OCSP. I tried reinstalling the new cert and even reissue it but to no avail.

Can anyone tell me how exactly can I purge the old revoked cert from getting in a way of the new cert? I believed this has caused downtime to my site.

Is this an issue with SSL provider or server side? The hosting company kept bouncing this and blaming SSL provider while the other one pointed me to the hosting company.

Comment: What kind of hosting setup do you have? Maybe I'm to evangelical, but is LetsEncrypt an option for you?

Comment: You should reach your hosting provider, it is certainly their issue. Seems like, they failed to replace revoked certificate in HTTPS bindings. It is not an SSL provider's issue.

Answer (score -1):

Very simple solution for such issue is just redirect all https request to http using 301  and visa versa.

this will refresh browser and server ssl caching.

hope this will help.

Comment: Hi vrkansagara, welcome to Information Security! Can you explain a little bit more about how this works and when you can/cannot use it?

Comment: You can’t redirect from https to http for a revoked cert. the browser will fail before that happens.

Comment: @ISMSDEV Can you provide any good article on https will not redirect http ! This will be useful for other as well.

Comment: I’m not saying you can’t redirect between protocols. But you cannot redirect a failed https handshake, due to an invalid cert, to http. If you could that would render https cert verification pointless. Google “redirect https invalid cert to http” plenty of articles, some even on here.